# Did I do this estimation correctly?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

I was looking online for cars with APR rates just to see if I can find the monthly and yearly interest. Just to practice what I know, and I want to see if I did this correctly.

2023 Chevrolet Camaro price at 75,285

Down Payment is 20% so I divide it by 100 to get 0.2
I also divide 75,285 by 100 to get 752.85

I multiply 752.85 by 0.2 to get 150.57

Now, I multiply 150.57 by 100 to get the down payment = 15,057

So 75,285 - 15,057 = 60,228 left to pay off

Okay now, the estimated payments are 1,164/month. 5.99% APR for 60 months

My answers:

The interest per month is an average of $50

Annually you'll be paying $599

In the total of 60 months = 5 years. You would of paid $2,995 of interest.

Did I do this correctly? If not please explain, Thank you for your time.